# How to use ESC sequences to set foreground colors?

Tags: c, colors, windows-console

I'm writing a dynamic color palette for console terminal. The thing is to get ANSI ESC sequences to work within a default wincon terminal is enough to set those flags to the handles of the console:

```
    DWORD dwRequestedOutModes = ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING | DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN;
    DWORD dwRequestedInModes = ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT;
```

but using them is another thing. Right now my console engine outputs screen buffer made with `CHAR_INFO` with `WriteConsoleOutputW()`, but `CHAR_INFO` itself supports only 16 default scheme colors.

Using `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX` is again limited by 16 colors, but this time custom.

Using console ESC sequences is a good point, but the problem is I've found only examples of using `printf()`. For my project printf is too slow and unreliable, is there any other way to assign ESC sequence to each symbol in buffer.

Here is an example of my code:

```
WriteConsoleOutputW(this->m_hConsole, this->localFrame, (COORD){ (short)this->m_nScreenWidth, (short)this->m_nScreenHeight }, (COORD){ 0,0 }, &this->m_rectWindow);
```

Drawing routine: localFrame is CHAR_INFO pointer

```
void PrintFrameW(void* self, int x, int y, wchar_t character, short color)
{
    struct c_class* this = self;
    if (x >= 0 && x < this->nFrameLength&&y >= 0 && y < this->nFrameHeight)
    {
        this->localFrame[y*this->nFrameLength + x].Char.UnicodeChar = character;
        this->localFrame[y*this->nFrameLength + x].Attributes = color;
    }
}
```

It looks like C++ code, but this one is my self made C with classes, so it is ANSI-C wrap-up made for educational purposes.

**The question is:** How to colorize the output of the console with Escape sequences, and where to put them, with it being able to print something like this:

[image]

using ' ' char(space) and setting background color to ESC [48 ; 2 ; r ; g ; b or ESC [48 ; 5 ; s

Comment: You might want to look at [Console virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences)

Comment: @lurker I did, but I haven't found anything except for printf(). I need something for applying ESC to every char on screen, with them all defined as spaces for the entirety of terminal

Comment: You can use `printf` or `putc`. Why can't you use one of these to output escape codes and individual characters?

Comment: @lurker because there are 320*84 of them and each one can change its state. It is a picture

Comment: Obviously you need loops and variables. That would be true regardless of how you output the codes. For example, looping on values of `r`, `g`, and/or `b` with `printf("\x1b[\x30;\x2;%c;%c;%c", r, g, b)`. or something like that...

Comment: @lurker with printf i cannot specify coordinate, I'm writing somewhat of a game engine, printf will just slow it down drastically.

Comment: You can specify coordinate with `printf` with the proper format string. However, you can also use `putc`.

Comment: So to make it faster you need to build a character buffer yourself and put in all the relevant codes. You can then printf or fwrite the whole buffer in one go.

Comment: By the way, you will probably never get it fast enough by doing whole screen refreshes. You will almost certainly need to use the cursor positioning commands and minimal redraws.

Comment: There are plenty of references eg http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the low-level function can be done to write something in console without any checks. For this it's required only two things: char buffer and WriteFile().

```
char lfbuf[5120U] = { '\x1b','[','3','8',';','2',';','1','0','0',';','0',';','0','m','w','\0' };



        DWORD const lfbuf_length = (DWORD)(17);

        DWORD written;
        WriteFile(hOut, lfbuf, lfbuf_length, &written, NULL);
```

where hOut is a console handle. Turns out this one is being processed by the terminal and is fast, as it lasts only for couple thousands of ticks. I had to reverse the entire printf() to find this one out. Maybe there is something faster, but WriteFile is irreversible, it stops the execution when I reach out for assembly.