# How can MSVC with /TC option compile corecrt libs(like stdio), written in C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, printf, stdout

In order to find answer to my own question [How to use ESC sequences to set foreground colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472554/how-to-use-esc-sequences-to-set-foreground-colors)

I tried to find out how `printf()` itself works, and then maybe create my own function, which only accepts RGB and then automatically applies this color as an escape sequence to VT100 emulator of windows console. But eventually as I started digging into the code I discovered, that the most of IO, as well as stdin and stdout are written in C++ as well as string validator for printf format string.

As I was taught, in order to execute the program, compiler does all-the-way-back inclusion up to point, where all the text from all the included libs is pasted in your code. But my compiler is set to C only, so it can't compile C++ code. How could this happen? And is there other way to write stdout with escape codes already known to me(\033[%d;%d;%d;%d;%dm), though pushing the limitations of the console output?

Comment: The system headers should generally be considered black boxes.  Their details are whatever the implementation needs them to be.  All that you can or should rely on is that they provide the declarations and macro definitions they are specified to provide.

Comment: @JohnBollinger this situation occurred because of me being unable to get what I want in good manner (provide some direct approach functions to the terminal) was told to use slow and ineffective more uniform approach, as I am a greater hater of magic, I want less of obscurity and more functionality

Comment: Write in assembly if you want full control of all the details.  If you write in a higher-level language (and C isn't all that high level) then write to that language's standard, and possibly to *documented* details of a particular implementation of that language and of your target environment.  There is no magic in that; it is simply using the set of abstractions you've chosen.

Comment: First of, MSVC doesn't have C only compiler. They have C++ compiler. Second of, the language in which CRT library function is written is irrelevant. The code is already compiled and available to you. The only thing which matters is C ABI, which is maintained by using `extern "C"` in header file for said function.

Comment: @SergeyA that makes sense